# Prove the Ring Homomorphism is Surjective

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Prove the following homomorphism is surjective.
$$f : Z → \frac{Z}{3Z} × \frac{Z}{5Z}$$

I completely get the questions and i can prove it by working out a corresponding pre-image for all of $\frac{Z}{3Z} × \frac{Z}{5Z}$.

But how do i give a formal proof if i change the question and ask

for any $(p,q)=1$ Prove the following homomorphism is surjective.
$$f : Z → \frac{Z}{pZ} × \frac{Z}{qZ}$$

I feel we may have to use Bezout's identity but don't know how to. 
any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You never defined $f$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think the idea is to send z to (z+pZ,z+qZ).

Comment: It is sufficient to produce (1,0) as a homomorphic image. (0,1) is produced similarly.

Comment: pn+qm=1 so qm=1-pn. So (qm,qm)=(1,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Chinese remainder theorem to show that $f: {Z/pZ} \times {Z/qZ} \to Z/(pqZ)$ is bijective. That's all you should need.

Comment: i had that hunch but cant get to see it properly can u elaborate please

Comment: elaborated a bit.

Comment: Hmmm i dont see why thats enough to show its surjective

Comment: sorry i meant to say BIJECTIVE. edited again lol

Comment: i get it is enough now but how i can show this now ?

Comment: It really is, in a strong sense, equivalent between your original claim and the chinese remainder theorem. You can look up proofs of the chinese remainder theorem. Just don't get the abstract algebra versions in terms of ideals, you want the elementary number thoery versions in terms of integers and modulo.

Comment: i got it man/woman Thanks

Comment: @MRK IF you don't yet know CRT you get get the surjectiveness immediately from the Bezout idenity - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one can immediately read off a CRT solution directly from the Bezout identity:

$\quad jp + kq = 1\,\Rightarrow\,\begin{align}{kq\equiv 1\pmod p}\\jp\equiv 1\pmod q\end{align}\,\ $ thus $\,\ x = bjp + akq \ \Rightarrow \begin{align}{x\equiv a\pmod p}\\x\equiv b\pmod q\end{align}$

i.e. $\ {\rm mod}\ (p,q)\!:\,\ \begin{align}kq \equiv (1,0)\\ jp\equiv (0,1)\end{align}\,\Rightarrow\, (a,b) = a(1,0)+b(0,1) \equiv akq + bjp $

which reveals the innate *linearity*, i.e. how the general solution $\,(a,b)\,$ can be generated as a linear combination of the "basis" solutions $\,(1,0)\,$ and $\,(0,1).\,$  This will become clearer when one studies the ring-theoretic form of CRT (and modules).

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ker f = 15 \mathbb Z$ has index $15$, the image of $f$ has size $15$ and so $f$ is surjective.

The same argument works in general when $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

(Invoking the Chinese remainder theorem sounds wrong to me because the argument above gives the simplest proof of the Chinese remainder theorem when the ring is $\mathbb Z$.)